# Google Sheets SUMPRODUCT/COUNTIF formula question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I am currently working on a google sheet where I'm counting the number of schools that have a device assigned. One of the ranges that I'm pulling contains duplicate device serials from another column.

My question is what would be a good formula given that i'm counting column A but i want to not include anything that might be a duplicate in column C.

For example:

A---------------B-----------C
RHS---------date------0011

EHS---------date------0082

EHS---------date------0064

EHS---------date------0082

SHS---------date------0058

I want to count EHS in Column A but exclude the duplicate number in Column C. The answer should be 2

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTUNIQUEIFS()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(C1:C,A1:A,"EHS")
```